# Generics in Rust :: mismatched types expected struct `Token<'_, T>` found struct `Token<'_, i32>

Tags: generics, rust

I'm having issues with the return type.
Sorry for the bad code.
I am learning Rust and didn't find the answer to this problem.
I also tried the Rust book, but with no success.

Error:
mismatched types
expected struct `Token<'_, T>`
found struct `Token<'_, {integer}>`

Code:

```rust
    struct Token<'a, T: 'a> {
        token_type: &'a str,
        value e: T,
    }
 
    impl<'a, T> Token<'a, T> {
      pub fn new(ttype: &'a str, value: T) -> Token<'a, T> {
        Token {
            token_type: ttype,
            value,
        }
      }
    }

    struct Lexer<'a> {
        input_code: &'a str,
        pos: i32,
        current_char: String,
    }

    impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
        pub fn get_next_token<T>(&self) -> Token<T> {
            while self.current_char != EOF {
 
                if self.current_char == SPACE {
                    self.skip_whitespace();
                    continue;
                }
    
                if DIGITS.to_owned().contains(&self.current_char) {
                    let number: i32 = self.create_integer();
                    let token = Token::new(INTEGER, number);
                    return token;
                }

                if self.current_char == "+" {
                    self.advace();
                    let token = Token::new(SUM, "+");
                    return token;
                }
            }

            let token = Token::new(EOF, 0);
            token
        }

...more code
```

Comment: Could you point where this error comes from? Your code doesn't compile due to *many* typos and missing definitions.

Comment: I'm sorry. I got this error on "return token;"

Comment: You declare that `get_next_token` returns `Token<T>`, but you later return `Token<i32>`. You should probably change function signature and remove generic parameter `T`.

Comment: You must also specify Token's lifetime. I guess it's `'static`, but I can't know since you didn't show what `INTEGER` is. Also there probably isn't any need for bound `T: 'a` on `Token` struct since it doesn't seem to be any corelation between this two. And lastly `token_type` should probably be an `enum` and not a `&str` since string-typed API's are bad idea in general, and terrible in Rust, which gives much more powerful tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your function says it will return a `Token<T>`.

In this block you return a `Token<i32>` (this is where the error message is coming from).

```
if DIGITS.to_owned().contains(&self.current_char)
    let number: i32 = self.create_integer();
    let token = Token::new(INTEGER, number);
    return token;
}
```

And in this block you return a `Token<&'static str>()`.

```
if self.current_char == "+" {
    self.advace();
    let token = Token::new(SUM, "+");
    return token;
}
```

Neither of these match your return type of `Token<T>`. Which really states that your function can return a token of *any* `T` the caller wants. This is a very hard contract to fulfill!

The solution to this is likely to remove the generic from `Token<T>` and instead have an `enum` over all your possible Tokens (it looks like you're close to this idea with the `token_type` field). Your `get_next_token` function would then just return a `Token` and the caller would have to figure out what the Token actually contains.

Comment: No success. But thanks for the comment. It gave me an idea to change the implementation.